# Website with Quickbooks Online Integration without Sign in

Tags: integration, quickbooks-online

I'm looking for a solution where a customer will fill out a payment form (subscription base) and customer information form on my website. The payment will go to the QuickBooks Merchant Service and charge them every month automatically. We will also add the customer info to QuickBooks Online.

How can I do this without a sign in process since the customer will have no QuickBooks account or QuickBooks Merchant account. Also can I achieve this with no e-commerce storefront like BigCommerce.

I tried using the QuickBooks PHP DevKit "consolibyte/quickbooks-php" and everything works but you have to sign in first.

I was searching some more and will this help me out > "QuickBooks PHP DevKit for the Web Connector". I'll keep reading the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I do this without a sign in process since the customer will have no QuickBooks account or QuickBooks Merchant account.

Use this library:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

And follow the quick-start guide here:

- for QuickBooks ONLINE: http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Intuit_Partner_Platform_Quick-Start
- for QuickBooks for WINDOWS: http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Quick-Start

> Also can I achieve this with no e-commerce storefront like BigCommerce.

Yes.

> everything works but you have to sign in first.

You have to sign in ONCE. Exactly ONCE. And then you NEVER NEED TO SIGN IN AGAIN. *Of course* you have to sign in at least once - how else would QuickBooks know that it's actually you wanting to exchange data with QuickBooks, and not some random hacker half-way across the world?

The sign-in is to authenticate and connect to QuickBooks THE VERY FIRST TIME ONLY. After THE FIRST SIGN IN, *YOU NEVER HAVE TO SIGN IN AGAIN* and can communicate without a sign-in.

This is standard OAuth, like every other OAuth platform on the planet. You sign in once to a authenticate yourself, and then you can do whatever you want from there on out.

Comment: Thank you. The login issue really threw me off. I'll continue using the QuickBooks PHP DevKit. Thanks again.